# Maven is not able to find jaxb-api with OpenJDK 11 even though its present in the repository

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, java-11

I have a machine having Windows OS, it is used to build few WAR Projects. It has **Java 8 installed** on it. I am using **Maven 3.2.5** to build these WAR Projects. Everything is working fine. But as Java 8 will be a problem in future due to its end of free updates I thought of upgrading to OpenJDK 11.

**I downloaded OpenJDK 11 but did not install it** as I just wanted to try this for 1 of the project to start. I picked up one of the WAR Project to check if OpenJDK 11 works. This project is created using JHipster and Spring Boot. 
I changed the pom.xml for this project to use `spring-boot.version to 2.1.2` and `java.verion to 11` and also put the `jaxb-api, jaxb-impl, jaxb-runtime` and `javax.activation` enteries(as shown below) to avoid jaxb related dependency errors in Java 11.

In windows command prompt, I set the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` variables to OpenJDK11 and then I fire the `mvn clean compile package` command. As expected all jaxb related dependencies are downloaded in the maven repository but still maven is throwing error `NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException` while jaxb-api jar is still there in Maven repository. I tried to fire the command again but no luck.

Can anyone please guide me about the possible root cause or any workaround.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Use Maven 3.6.0 first.

Comment: My guess is this may have to do with the "split package" issue where classes with the same package name can't be in two different jar files.  That will cause class loading issues.

Comment: Edit your question and post the dependencies you added to your pom.xml.

Comment: @Michael-O Updated Maven to 3.6.0 but still the same error.

Comment: @Robert, dependencies added in the question

Comment: Do you pack the libraries into your WAR file or do you import them from the application-platform? Because NoClassDefFoundError usually means "I found the class but I don't have access to it".

Comment: Right now we are packing libs into WAR file only. But why would be any access issue here? Maven, code, jdk, repository everything is there on the same machine.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, upgrading to Java 11 from Java 8. Even after explicitly adding the XML bind dependencies in the project I am getting class not found exception. Wondering if you were able to resolve your issue and what approach you took.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working with the following POM

```
<properties>
    <maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>0.14.0</maven-jaxb2-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

//

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-b170127.1453</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

//

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-jaxb2-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>*.wsdl</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I have done the first 2 changes and getting the same error. What is the significance of the 3rd change. Sorry, but I didn't understand the wsdl thing here. Is this your example code location?

Comment: I have got the same error even after all the mentioned changes are done

Answer (score 1):

The reason maybe is modules after java9, so you should create a module-info.java file, more detail consults the related doc.

Comment: create the module-info.java in my project and added :module com.abc {
   requires java.xml.bind;
} but no luck, same issue

Answer (score 1):

Apparently only jars upgrade of various components are needed to support JDK11 in Java projects written using Java8. Module support is not needed until you want to create modular projects in the product and Import/Export of module is needed.

I have upgraded the Javaassist Jar as well along with the ones mentioned in question and everything started working fine after it.

```
<javassist.version>3.24.1-GA</javassist.version>
```

and as mentioned in question itself

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, I use spring-boot and java 11.
This help me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below into the start-class(such as SpringBootApplication):

```
@Bean
public TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcatFactory() {
    return new TomcatServletWebServerFactory() {
        @Override
        protected void postProcessContext(Context context) {
            ((StandardJarScanner) context.getJarScanner()).setScanManifest(false);
        }
    };
}
```