# How to resolve A required class was missing while executing : javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, jaxb

I have some code that uses JAXB API classes. When I run the  code with Java 11, at runtime I get errors indicating that "A required class was missing while executing" .

I am using jaxb version

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Error
org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.0.2155:sonar failed: A required class was missing while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.9.0.2155:sonar: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Is this version Issue? if I run same code on Java8 then working fine no issue has detected. but Java 11 I always getting this error

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need to include some more required dependencies apart from `glassfish`. Following are the additional dependencies, check for the latest versions and include them and try executing again:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0-b170127.1453</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Additionally check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54361901/7584240